# Write List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>> to text file?

Tags: c#, linq, file, list, dictionary

I was wondering if anyone knows a good way of writing this. I have a list of key value pairs. The key is a simple string and the value is a list of strings. I'm trying to write it out to an output file like so:

```
        File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\S\Downloads\output.txt",
            xEleAtt.Select(x => x.Key + " Val's: " + x.Value).ToArray());
```

However the output I get (which is kinda what I thought would happen) is this:

Queue0 Val's: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Queue1 Val's: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Queue2 Val's: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]

Has anyone got an idea of how I can print the contents of the list using linq written in the way i've wrote it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) to concatenate your `List<string>` into a single `string` with a given delimiter:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\S\Downloads\output.txt",
        xEleAtt.Select(x => x.Key + " Val's: " + 
        string.Join(",", x.Value.ToArray()).ToArray());
```

Comment: +1. The `ToArray` calls are not necessary if you're using .NET 4.0 or later.

Comment: Nice. I'll give it a try. I understand that it will separate them by comma in that case but if I wanted them to be separated by a new line could I use Environment.NewLine somehow?

Comment: @SuzanAydın: Sure. Just replace `string.Join(",", ...` with `string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ...`. If you want the `Key` to be repeated at the beginning of each line for its values, use King King's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\S\Downloads\output.txt",
    from kvp in input
    select kvp.Key + ": " + string.Join(", ", kvp.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Users\S\Downloads\output.txt",
         xEleAlt.SelectMany(x=> x.Value, (x,y)=> x.Key + " Val's: " + y).ToArray());

//Result
Queue0  ....
Queue0  ....
......
Queue1  ....
Queue1  ....
....
```

**NOTE**: I'm not sure if you want to join all the strings in the `List<string>` to make the value for each entry. If you want so, refer the answer of `Douglas`